# $T(n) = T(n/2 - \log(n)) +1$ using Substitution Method

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence: $$T(n) = T(n/2 - \log(n)) +1$$
How can this be solved using the substitution method?

I don't fully understand the theory of this method and I'm not sure how to apply it on this kind of recurrences;
I'm a beginner in this field and i would like a simple solution that i could understand.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want an exact solution, or do you want an approximation (e.g. big theta)?

Comment: I want an approximation. I guess it will be: big theta(log n), but I'm not sure how to use the Substitution Method to check my guess.